# How to make wifi list show duplicate SSID when different mac address

Tags: wi-fi, 7.1-nougat

I have a home modem and a repeater, both have the same SSID. at some cases  want to connect to one and not the other, but android automatically chooses the one with the highest signal strength which is not what I always want.

Is there anyway to make android display different wifi networks based on mac address instead of just SSID so that I can choose to which one I connect ?

I use android 7.1.1. and my phone is rooted.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using 3rd-party apps which priotise wi-fi networks for example: [WiFi Prioritizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.za.flash.wifiprioritizer)